# PARAMETROS GET envio

Tags: javascript, json, webservice

***Tengo este código js que recibe dos parámetros  día nombre  lo que quiero es pasarlos de forma get a esta otra pagina que se llama mad en la cual mandare los parámetros directos a un w service llamado días para que me traiga los resultados y los pinte en un div que se llama muestra***

```
$("#envia").click(function () {
              var datos={
                         dia: $("#nivel").val(),
                         nombre: $("#curp").val()
                        }; 

          $.ajax({
        url: "mad.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: datos,

        success: function (result) {
            $("#muestra").html(result);
        }
    })
});
```

***este es el js que resibe las variables pero no hace nada no se si las estoy recibiendo bien  no me marca ningun error simplemente no me muestra nada ***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var datos={
                         dia: $("#dia").val(),
                         nombre: $("#nombre").val()
                        }; 

            $.ajax({
                    url: 'wservice/dias.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: datos,
                })
            .done(function (respuesta) {

                  console.log("dia:"+respuesta.dia);
                  console.log("Nombre:"+respuesta.Nombre);
                  console.log("a:"+respuesta.a);
)}
)};
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo envias los datos por un get al web service y luego en otra pagina recibes los datos que haz enviado anteriormente al web service?

Comment: ¿La consola te lanza algún error?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez no , le mando los campos dia y nombre a la pagina mad.php ahi recojo los campos con $(document).ready(function () { ahi los mando esos dos campos a un web service que se llama dias y me retorna los datos console.log etc..  pero mi duda es si estoy recibiendo bien las vriables que van en a url , y no no me marca ningun error

Answer (score 0):

Hola no me quedó muy claro si los datos que recibes en "mad.php" los guardas en un input para luego recuperarlos y enviarlos a "dias.php" de ser así tu código tendría que funcionar correctamente.
Si tu quieres obtener los campos directamente de la url podrias hacerlo con la siguiente función

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (results==null){
     return null;
  }
  else{
   return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
  }
}
```

Basicamente esta funciona busca en la url los parametros por el nombre de los mismos. La función no es de mi autoria los créditos al autor. [Fuente del Codigo](https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/1296a08)

- Solucion con tu codigo de ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var datos = {
 dia: $.urlParam('nombre'), //Aqui Utilizas la funcion ($.urlParam) para obtener los campos desde la URL
 nombre: $.urlParam('dia')
 }; 
console.log(datos);
$.ajax({
      url: "wservice/dias.php",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: datos,
 })
.done(function (respuesta) {
 console.log("dia:"+respuesta.dia);
 console.log("Nombre:"+respuesta.Nombre);
 console.log("a:"+respuesta.a);
})
});
```